# Functions inside a function in Julia

Tags: julia

In Julia, I have a function for a complicated simulation, `monte_carlo_sim()` that involves many parameters. Inside this function, I need to call many other functions. I could write stand-alone functions *outside* of `monte_carlo_sim()`, but then I'd need to pass many parameters-- many of which are constant inside this function-- which would sacrifice elegance and clarity (and perhaps not take advantage of the fact that these are constant variables?). Is there a performance reason to not include functions within functions? As a toy example here, the temperature `T` is constant, and if I don't want to pass this variable to my function `compute_Boltzmann()`, I could do the following. Is there anything wrong with this?

```
function monte_carlo_sim(temp::Float64, N::Int)
    const T = temp

    function compute_Boltzmann(energy::Float64)
         return exp(-energy/T)
    end

    # later call this function many times
    for i = 1:1000
        energy = compute_energy()
        b = compute_Boltzmann(energy)
    end
end
```

Alternatively, I could define a new const type `SimulationParameters` and pass this to `compute_Boltzmann` instead, and writing `compute_Boltzmann` outside of the `monte_carlo_sim` function as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32971681/how-to-pass-parameter-list-to-a-function-in-julia)? Is this better? I'd be passing more information than I'd need in this case, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since google led me here, perhaps I add a comment:

Nested functions used to be slower, see for instance [this discussion](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/4428#issuecomment-25989450) on github... in 2013. But not any more: running exactly the tests there on v0.6, they are all the same speed now.

This is still true for me if (like the question) the inner function implicitly depends on things defined within the outer function, which would have to be passed explicitly if it were a free-standing function.

Comment: Google led me here as well, precisely because I have a large performance hit with the nested function. It is possible that this is because my nested function returns several parameters however.

Comment: Google brought me here as well, but the code in the question no longer works it seems (on julia 1.7.2). Getting error "syntax: unsupported `const` declaration on local variable around"

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, code clarity is very important so you should focus on that on the first place. If you feel like functions within functions is your style and helps you (and your colleagues) understand your script better than do it.
As for performance you can always compare the 2 implementations by using the `@time` macro. I wouldn't expect to see your functions within function implementation to suffer but it's always worth checking.

For more info on how to use `@time` and write high-performance code read the article [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/).